# Difference between tables where 1 to 3 relationship on key field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a table using SQL server that creates a table of differences between the two. The tricky part about this that I haven't found in other posts is that one table is single "Account" data like below:

```
TABLE A      
Account  Security ID  Sec Name   Shares
-------  -----------  ---------  ------
1        Sec1         Security1  20000
1        Sec2         Security2  50000
1        Sec3         Security3  10000
1        Sec4         Security4  35000
```

and the data that I want to compare this to is a group of "Accounts" (3 in this example):

```
TABLE B        
Parent_acct  Account  Security ID  Sec Name   Shares
-----------  -------  -----------  ---------  ------
Clone        200      Sec1         Security1  15000
Clone        200      Sec3         Security3  22000
Clone        200      Sec4         Security4  8000
Clone        300      Sec1         Security1  11000
Clone        300      Sec3         Security3  8500
Clone        300      Sec4         Security4  11200
Clone        400      Sec1         Security1  16000
Clone        400      Sec2         Security2  7800
Clone        400      Sec3         Security3  3500
```

I need some sql to locate security ID's included in Table A that are missing from Table B for each account

For instance, given the two tables above, I would expect the output below that tells me the security that is missing and what account it is missing from.

Hopefully, that makes sense.

I have used a cursor query to generate the data I need, however, I’m trying to create something that I can easily apply to Crystal Reports and a cursor query is not useful for that.

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this.

```
Output    
Account   Security ID  Sec Name
(From B)  (From A)     (From A)
-------   -----------  ---------
200       Sec2         Security2
300       Sec2         Security2
400       Sec4         Security4
```

My query so far:

```
select * FROM
(SELECT * from 
(select p.acct_cd, s.ext_sec_id, s.sec_name, p.qty_sod
from csm_Security s, cs_position p
where s.sec_id = p.sec_id
and p.acct_cd = '329'
and s.sec_typ_cd in ('COM','FSTK','ADR')) A
cross join 
(select distinct child_acct_cd
cs_fund_config fc
where fc.parent_acct_cd IN ('clone_as')) B) AAccounts,
(select fc.child_acct_cd, s.ext_sec_id, s.sec_name, p.qty_sod
from csm_Security s, cs_position p, cs_fund_config fc
where s.sec_id = p.sec_id
and fc.child_acct_cd = p.acct_cd
and fc.parent_acct_cd IN ('clone_as')
and s.sec_typ_cd in ('COM','FSTK','ADR')) BAccounts
where AAccounts.ext_sec_id *= BAccounts.ext_sec_id
and AAccounts.child_acct_cd *= BAccounts.child_acct_cd
```

Comment: In your sample data, Table A has all its accounts set to 1. Is that an error? looks like those should be 200 or 300 or 400. BTW, please try my answer.

Comment: It's not an error. I guess that you could say that it is sort of a model account. Comparing the positions in account 1 accross the positions from the three accounts in Table B.

Comment: I get it now; I did a bad assumption so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Tricky one! Try this (I can't test it, watch out for syntax errors):

```
SELECT BAccounts.Account, A.SecurityID, A.SecName
 from TableA  A
  cross join (select distinct Account
               from TableB) BAccounts
  left outer join TableB B
   on B.Account = BAccounts.Account
    and B.SecurityID = A.SecurityID
 where B.SecurityID is null
```

The logic is:

- Start with TableA
- Join each row with all possible accounts found in table B
- Now left-outer-join it with Table B, using B's Account and A's SecurityId
- If not found, B.SecurityId is null, and we have the offending Account via the subquery

Comment: Here is what I have been working with similar to what you provided. It gets me close, but if I try and outer left join on the last two lines, I get an error:

Comment: Server: Msg 1016, Level 15, State 3, Line 23
Outer join operators cannot be specified in a query containing joined tables. Here is the sql:

Comment: I've added it to the original info above.

Comment: In the first subquery after the cross join you are missing a `from`. Separating this subquery from the next with a comma will produce an I-don’t-know-what join, but as the last stated one was “cross join” it makes me *very* nervous. And you really want to use `left outer join` instead of the old `*=` syntax, search Stack Overlow with “old outer join syntax” for discussions; in fact, this error is another reason why it should be avoided.

Comment: I replaced the comma with a left join on table BAccounts. and that did the trick! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Just to mention, when you get a "final" answer to a question on Stack Overflow, you should mark it as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this should be a relatively straight forward outer join.  It's called an Outer Join because we want to include the rows from one table that don't have a match in the second table as well as the ones that do.  Use the keywords `LEFT JOIN` because we put table A on the left of the join clause, this indicates we are doing an outer join and the rows from A that don't have a match in B should be included.  The where clause will select only those rows.  You won't be able to get the Account number from B with this of course, because there is no row in table B for this Security Id.  The Account number from A should be good though, right?

```
SELECT
  A.Account,
  A.[Security Id]
  A.[Sec Name]
FROM
  A LEFT JOIN B 
    ON A.[Security Id] = B.[Security Id]
    AND A.Account = B.Account
WHERE
  B.[Security Id] IS NULL
```

Comment: That's what I thought. However, the problem with a straight outer join is that if the security id is held in one of the "group" accounts from table B, but not all three, it won't show up in the output as a differnce. From the example above, Security ID 'Sec2' is in Account 400, but not in accounts 200 or 300. Even though it matches to account 400, I still want to see the differences for the other two accounts as described as the output in my original question. Thanks

Comment: I think I misunderstood the relationships.  If you want to select from A all the Pairs of Account and Security ID where there is not match Pair of the same columns in Table B then you can add an additional constraint to the join clause like so: `A LEFT JOIN B ON A.[Security Id] = B.[Security ID] AND A.Account = B.Account`

Comment: It doesn't work because A.Account and B.Account are different things.

Comment: OIC now, the account column from table A is not involved in the relationship at all, then.  Hmm.